# Cheats for the Sims on Windows Phone 7

Tags: the-sims-3, cheats

The missus just got Sims3 on WP7, apparently it's driving her nuts and is very slow paced (?). Anyway, is anyone aware of cheats for this phone? iPhone ones don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the presence of achievements in the WP7 version, cheats are not included, as they break the achievement mechanics.

The few games that do include a cheat mode, usually disable achievements to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

There are no cheats availbale in the smartphone-game